# How to refresh the page until it is properly loaded (due to server error like error 502)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a website using selenium web driver in python. It gets stuck when it does not get the clickable element due to server error for which the page is not properly loaded. I want to create a function which will automatically refresh the page after 15 seconds if it does not load properly (more specifically if it does not get the clickable element).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://addguru.in/user/index.php")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

username=driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("-------")

password=driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("-------")

driver.implicitly_wait(40)

driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit_btn").click()
""" I want a function here which automatically refresh the page after each 15 sec if  the submit-btn is not clickable (due to propely loading problem) """
browser.find_element_by_id("checkCbtaskdiv").click()


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking quickly, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43023812/2327328), you can set the response of `driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit_btn")` without the `.click()` to a variable and then check if that variable is not `None`

```
while elements is None:
    elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit_btn")

for e in elements:
    e.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should at least post a warning in your assertions when that does happen. That way you know what errors occurred. If you do that, the following would help you...

Add this on page initialization or as soon as it begins to load the page in question. You could also do this on any page, really.

```
driver.execute_script('''

    window.errorCount = 0;
    window.onerror = function (error, url, line, column, errorMessage) {

        errorCount ++;
        //** Add whatever you like from the error information to this json string.
        errorJson = '{"code":"' + error.Status + '", "error":"' + error.Status + '", "details":"' + errorMessage + '"}';
        //Appending hidden input with details to document. All console errors can be scraped this way, or just ones that stop page load if you like.
        $("body").append("<input type='hidden' class='console-error-saved' id='" + errorCount 
     + '"' value='" + errorJson + "'");

    }
''')
```

Then, from your Selenium scripts, while waiting for an expected element to appear, if that wait times out and still does not find the element, run this:

```
pageErrors = driver.execute_script('''
    var json = ""; 
    var errors = $('.console-error-saved'); 
    for(var x=0; x < errors.length; x++) { 

        json += $(errors[x]).text(); 
        if(x < errors.length - 1) { 
            json += ","; 
        } 

    } 
    return "[" + json + "]";
''')
```

Now parse the json from Python to get an object from the string. Look for specific errors such as 502, 503 etc. and report them, and then call a refresh command

```
import json
errors = json.loads(pageErrors)
#... look at the errors and handle them as needed.
# If qualifying error occurred, refresh the page and do your checks again.
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to So. Here is the method.

```
# interval - refresh time
# maxTime - maximum time to wait (rather going into infinite loop)
def refresh_browser_until_element_present(locator_type, locator, interval, maxTime):
    startTime = datetime.now()
    elements = []
    while ((datetime.now() - startTime).seconds<maxTime and len(elements) ==0):
        time.sleep(interval)
        driver.refresh()
        if locator_type == 'xpath':
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(locator)
        elif locator_type == 'css':
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(locator)
```

How to use the method:

```
refresh_browser_until_element_present('css','#checkCbtaskdiv',15,120)
```