# Cannot find next button on the page

Tags: python, selenium, class

I'm trying to **scrape** data from LinkedIn by using Python and Selenium.

After getting names on the page I want to find the "Next" button and click it.

The "Next" button located at the highlighted text below (this is from **Firefox** page by the way):
[image]

So I do:

```
next_button_find=browser.find_element_by_class_name('next')
next_button_find.click()
```

but it gives this error when its executed:

[image]

I also tried based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021434/click-button-by-find-element-by-class-name-not-working-python-selenium-webdriver):

```
next_button_find=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('next')
next_button_find.click()
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Thx in advance!

Comment: this element has class `artdeco-button__text`, not `next`. It has text `Next` but it is NOT class name.

Comment: Text `Next` is in tag `<span>` which is in tag `<button>` and you should search `<button>`because button is clickable. `<span>` is not clickable.

Comment: becuase this `<button>` has `id=ember320` then you should rather use `browser.find_element_by_id('ember320').click()`

Comment: That id will keep on changing !! Next button id is not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
next_button_find = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".artdeco-pagination__button--next")
next_button_find.click()
```

PS: The `id` (ember320) looks like a dynamic.

Hope it helps you!