# Why am I not able to use sendkeys to enter text into textbox?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I am trying to enter text on this webpage: https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020

This is the code that I have so far

```
from selenium import webdriver

import os

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



chrome_driver = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

browser.get('https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020')

#clicks agreement to morningstar's terms of service
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ms-agreement > input'))).click()

#tries to clear text box at bottom right hand side of page
browser.find_element_by_class_name('qs-ui-ipt qs-pageutil-input').clear()

#tries to enter '2' in text box
browser.find_element_by_class_name('qs-ui-ipt qs-pageutil-input').send_keys(2)
```

I am trying to enter the number '2' into the text box that is at the bottom right of the chart.

This is the error message I receive when I run the code listed above: 'Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".qs-ui-ipt qs-pageutil-input"}'

I see most tutorials use 'find_element_by_id' to run this process but the element on the web page doesn't have an ID associated with it. I'm not sure if I need an ID or not to execute this process but I thought I might as well share. I also tried to find the element by XPath and by CSS selector but it didn't work.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following **css selector**.

```
driver.get("https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.button_blue.agree"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.qs-ui-ipt.qs-pageutil-input"))).clear()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.qs-ui-ipt.qs-pageutil-input"))).send_keys("2")
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use find_element_by_class_name for compound class names. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021434/click-button-by-find-element-by-class-name-not-working-python-selenium-webdriver).

Answer (score 0):

U can solve this problem by using `WebDriverWait` & `CSS Selector`. Here is the entire code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import os

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



chrome_driver = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

browser.get('https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020')

#clicks agreement to morningstar's terms of service
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ms-agreement > input'))).click()

#tries to clear text box at bottom right hand side of page
txtbox = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ms-glossary > div > table > tfoot > tr > td > div > input'))) #Usage of CSS_SELECTOR instead of CLASS_NAME; usage of WebDriverWait

txtbox.click()

txtbox.clear()
#tries to enter '2' in text box
txtbox.send_keys(2)
```

Hope that this helps!